# "new XSSFWorkbook" not working in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, xlsx

I am currently trying to set up an existing JAVA project in IntelliJ IDEA.
The project just won't run past the below posted code snippet on my machine.

```
    try {

        this.wb = new XSSFWorkbook (inputStream);
        out.print_c("42");

    }
```

I already updated all my dependencies (my Setup is posted at the end of the post), checked the Excel file for any kind of protection (it has none), but I still get the following error messages:

> org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException: org/apache/poi/POIXMLTypeLoader
>       at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:66)
>       at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:648)
>       at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:180)
>       at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:286)
>       at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:307)
>       at excel_manager.ExcelFileReader.readExcelSheet(ExcelFileReader.java:80)
>       at excel_manager.BBB.readBBB(BBBReader.java:52)
>       at BBB.BBBPlanManager.(BBBPlanManager.java:31)
>       at main.AAAAProjectManager.main(AAAAProjectManager.java:76)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:56)
>       at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:63)
>       ... 8 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/POIXMLTypeLoader
>       at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CalcChainDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.CalculationChain.readFrom(CalculationChain.java:56)
>       at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.CalculationChain.(CalculationChain.java:51)
>       ... 14 more

Setup:

IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2 x64

jdk1.8.0_221

[Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIEPr.png)

I hope anyone has an idea what could be the problem here.

Thank you in advance.

Dennis

Comment: Please provide project example for investigation.

Comment: In your image the xmlBeans dependency is red. Try fixing this red warning ( as poi use xml-beans to load stuff ) and check if it will work. Just a suggestion if you already haven't done that before creating example project

Comment: Sadly I cannot provide a project example.

Comment: @MichaelMichailidis I updated the path to xmlBeans but the error remains the same.

Comment: Just a note.. When we ask for a project example we do not mean yours.. Create a mock project with the minimal configuration that would reproduce the problem. ( And not joking here.. some people find the solution while building the mock projects ). Without something in my hands I cannot investigate / guess what your problem may be to provide a solution. I am sorry